# Obtain numbers after the decimal point by "numericality"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
validates :weight_in_grams, numericality: true
```

In a Ruby on Rails app, I coded like the above in one of the models. When I input 0.5 in the form, the DB got 0, but I didn't specify `only_integer: true` so am wondering why. Can anyone help me out? I use Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 4.2.6.

Comment: what's the type of your db column?

Comment: it's decimal. i just searched about the type and knew that we can specify the number of digits in the db... well, thanks a lot for the hint.